# How to download the MVC cshtml in PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I do have a cshtml view and want the functionality to download it in PDF format.
can i have the some guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Rotativa which is also available in Nuget. [See here](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/export-asp-net-mvc-view-to-pdf-in-3-quick-steps/) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/818197/Generate-PDF-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Using-Rotativa)

Then you can just call:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
{
    return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("YourActionResult");
}
```

This will generate your pdf for you.